# implement dynamic detail view in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

So I have a listview with multiple items, so when each item is clicked it will go to a detail page, but how do I fill out the detail view with dynamic contents? Specifically, how do I capture the key, which is the clicked item's inner html, and when I query some dynamic contents, how do I put them in the detail view? The methods I tried include 1) use click event for each item, but the event does not trigger, is that normal? 2) I tried the live event on the detail view page with pagebeforeshow, but it does not trigger either. Please help.

Comment: you might want to add a code example... you could use http://jsfiddle.net for that...

Answer (score 0):

Many approaches exist to do this. Here is one idea that may help you:

In your `listview`, specify a data ID for each of the hyperlinks in the list item. The definitions could look like:

```
<li><a data-id="some-identifier">My Title</a></li>
```

For all the items the `<li>` items in the list, you then have a single click handler, which would use the `data-id` to initialize the detail page. The click handler would look something like this (my apologies if this is out of data, I have not recently used jQuery Mobile, so there may be an updated, better approach):

```
$('#my-listview-id').delegate('a', 'vclick', function () {
     alert ('user selected something: ' +  $(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

The alert will show you the ID the user selected. So in the click handler you can update the detail page.